# Can I use <textarea> to escape tags?

Tags: html, escaping

Are tags inside `<textarea>` elements supposed to be considered text or markup? In most browsers, tags inside a `<textarea>` element are ignored, and the browser parses the content as if the tags were escaped:

```
<textarea>
  In HTML you use <p> to make a paragraph, check it out:
  
  <p> My paragraph </p>
</textarea>
```

In the example above, Chrome thinks there is no `<p>` element inside the textarea: inspecting the DOM, it's all just one big text node. So the parsing inside a `<textarea>` behaves a lot like the deprecated `<xmp>`.

Can I rely on this escaping behavior? I can't figure out [the spec](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/form-elements.html#the-textarea-element), and [Mozilla goes out of its way to emphasize that I must escape my `<`s:](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/xmp)

> Use the <pre> element or, if semantically adequate, the <code> element instead. Note that you will need to escape the '<' character as '&lt;' and the '&' character as '&amp;' to make sure they are not interpreted as markup.

Comment: Anything within the textarea is text